# Replace a variable in a function with the value in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, tostring

I am looking for a way to replace a variable in a function with its actual value. I am going to convert this function into a string and send via a HTTP request and thus need to convert the variables inside the function with their values.

```
let x = Math.random();

let funcString = function () {
    let y = x + 10;
    return y;
}.toString();

// Send funcString as a parameter
```

For eg. in the above code if I send `funcString` as it is, whoever receiving it will have no idea what is the value of `x`.

Since I am ultimately sending a string I would like to send

> `"function () {let y = 0.53 + 10; return y;}"` (assuming
>   `Math.random()` produced 0.53 at runtime).

Is there any way to do this?

I am doing this in a nodejs project so a npm module would be fine by me too.

Comment: It would probably be more efficient (and better practice) to just send an object containing all the current values of the variables. i.e., send `{functionBody: "...", vars: {x: 0.53}}`. That way you wouldn't have to do string replacements in the function and worry about injection, syntax errors, etc.

Comment: why are you doing this? the value of y is determined so why not send just the value?

Comment: I'd also echo the question of why do that at all instead of sending the *result*? What is the benefit of sending the function to be evaluated elsewhere when you have all the information in the current context? Usually if you *do* need to calculate something in a different context, you send the *parameters* but not the algorithm.

Comment: I am using Highcharts' export server to generate a chart and as such I need to send in custom functions. http://export.highcharts.com/

Comment: @SayakMukhopadhyay but I don't see that sending any strings. There are parameters and a callback. Are you trying to pass the string as a callback instead of an actual function?

Comment: That site formulates the string to send. The text box in question is the options text box. And the input in those boxes are simple trivial values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are returning this function as a `string`, just use **[`String#replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** to replace `x` occurrence with its value.

This is how you should use it:

```
funcString.replace('x', x)
```

**Demo:**

```js
let x = Math.random();

let funcString = function () {
    let y = x + 10;
    return y;
}.toString();

console.log(funcString.replace('x', x));
```

**Edit:**

If your variable has many occurrences and can be part of other variables just use  **[a `regex`](https://regex101.com/r/IgRAdv/1)** with `replace` method.

```
funcString.replace(/\bx\b/g, x)
```

**Demo:**

```js
let x = Math.random();

let funcString = function () {
    let y = x + 10;
    let fix ='true';
    let z = x * 2;
    return y;
}.toString();

console.log(funcString.replace(/\bx\b/g, x));
```

Comment: I have considered using `replace` but the thing is my function can have many `x` within it. Although, I guess since it's my code after all, I can give it a unique name.

Comment: Yes, it depends on your code, but in all cases you can use the variable name in a `regex` for replace.

Comment: Yeah, the global search works. I have just made sure to give a unique name to the variable I am replacing.

Answer (score 0):

use `replace` with `regex`, `g` will search all x-es

```js
let x = Math.random();

let funcString = function () {
    let y = x + 10;
    let a = x + 10;
    let b = x + 10;
    
    return y;
}.toString().replace(/x/g, x);

console.log(funcString);
```